# Filter Fields using Caml Query

Tags: caml-query

Normally I have this query, filtered with `MostrarHome eq 'No'`

```
 var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title&$orderby=Title asc&$filter=MostrarHome eq 'No'";
```

So I try to do it in Calm Query and it returns values but the filter doesn´t works:

```
 queryStringGaleria += string.Format("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MostrarHome'/><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>");
               queryStringGaleria += "<ViewFields>";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='FileRef' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Categoria' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Categoria_x003a_English' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Title' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='TitleEnglish' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Enlace' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='DescriptionEnglish' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Description' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "</ViewFields></View>";
```

How can I filter it correctly?

Comment: Are you opening the `<View>` tag somewhere not shown above?

Answer (score 2):

I think that that issue related to `MostrarHome` type value it's should be `integer` rather than `Boolean`

**Details:**

The `<Value Type='Boolean'>` take value `0 for false` and `1 for true`

Regarding `Yes / No field` contains `integer` data (1 for Yes and 0 for No option), so your query should look like,

```
queryStringGaleria += string.Format("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MostrarHome'/><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>");
               queryStringGaleria += "<View><ViewFields>";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='FileRef' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Categoria' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Categoria_x003a_English' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Title' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='TitleEnglish' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Enlace' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='DescriptionEnglish' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "<FieldRef Name='Description' />";
               queryStringGaleria += "</ViewFields></View>";
```

**Note :** I also put in mind , you might miss `<view>` tag as @ErinL said in her comment.so I put it at the above-modified query.

Comment: Both `Type='Integer'` and `Type='Boolean'` are valid for Yes/No fields

Comment: Thanks @ErinL for this info , I tried to do that for integer and worked properly , I think he may be miss <view> as you told him in your comment but if he has error in his query it's should not work but he said he return data but not filtered so let us wait for him,I am also will update my answer Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

1 for Yes(true) and 0 for No (false)

```
var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title&$orderby=Title asc&$filter=MostrarHome eq 0"; //false
```

or

```
var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title&$orderby=Title asc&$filter=MostrarHome eq 1"; //true
```